# How to check if the input is a valid number in Java

Tags: java, regex, numbers

Do I need to use regular expression? But the digit of the input is unknown.
Or there is a function in Java that does this?

Comment: What do you mean by *valid number*?

Comment: Ivaylo Strandjev, That is exactly what I was trying to do but the parseInt does not give a feedback when it fails. What I want is a signal so that I can prompt the user to redo the input.

Comment: Any combination of numbers 0-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance if you want to check if a `String` is a valid integer you can use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). In case the `String` does not store a number in valid format you will get a NumberFormatException so you can surround this code with a try/catch block.

Comment: Exceptions generally shouldn't be used for control flow. If you're running through this often and are just branching based on the numericalness of a number, then you shouldn't use an exception.

Comment: @Cruncher in this case writing a regex to check if the value is a valid integer(i.e. a 32 bit signed value) is very complex and the code readability and maintainability will suffer greatly from that. In fact I remember going into the same argument a few years ago with precisely your point, but in the end I gave up that there may be no better way to handle this situation.

Comment: Frankly there's no reason why this shouldn't be part of std lib if java wants to promote "ask permission" instead of "beg forgiveness".

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do but the parseInt does not give a feedback when it fails. What I want is a signal so that I can prompt the user to redo the input.

Comment: @JiajuShen What do you mean it doesn't give feedback when it fails?!?!? It jumps into the catch block instead of continueing in the try block. How is that not feedback?

Comment: I think I got what you mean. Thanks!